# Do I need to install each GRUNT plugin every time I start a new project?

Tags: gruntjs

Lets say I have a an existing project that has the LESS compiler for GRUNT installed.
If I start a new project do I need to reinstall the LESS compiler or is it already available somewhere on my system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can [install node modules either locally or globally (-g for global)](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/), but in general, you'll want to install locally so that all team members are using the same versions of the packages (specified in the package.json file.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install them each time. If you installed them globally (which isn't supported), then every time you wanted to update a plug-in for one project you would likely break all the other projects.

Your subsequent local installs would likely hit the NPM cache if the same version was being installed.